# GdxRuntimeException: Error reading pack file: uiskin.atlas

Tags: libgdx

First of all, I saw [GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779557/gdxruntimeexception-couldnt-load-file) but I think I have different problems here.

I'm trying to add a skin to a screen. The code is in Scala.

```
val skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json"))
```

I use libGdx 1.1.0. The uiskin.json is from [LibGdx's Github repo](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data/uiskin.json.).
Here is the errors:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading pack file: uiskin.atlas
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas$TextureAtlasData.<init>(TextureAtlas.java:187)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas.<init>(TextureAtlas.java:231)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas.<init>(TextureAtlas.java:226)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas.<init>(TextureAtlas.java:216)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.<init>(Skin.java:69)
    at com.pt2121.skintest.HelpScreen.show(HelpScreen.scala:39)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
    at com.pt2121.skintest.SkinTest.create(SkinTest.scala:8)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:236)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1512)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:43)
    at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:35)
    at libcore.util.BasicLruCache.get(BasicLruCache.java:54)
    at java.lang.Enum.getSharedConstants(Enum.java:209)
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:189)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap$Format.valueOf(Pixmap.java:49)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas$TextureAtlasData.<init>(TextureAtlas.java:120)
    ... 10 more
```

I've been searching for hours. I guess it might be something to do with Scala or libGdx version. (I have pretty much the same code in JAVA with libGdx 0.99 and it works fine.)
My project is at https://github.com/prt2121/skintest. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please Update your libgdx github repo , it should work fine after that.
Look into this : [Why "No com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ScrollPane$ScrollPaneStyle registered with name: default" error is coming and how to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23072624/why-no-com-badlogic-gdx-scenes-scene2d-ui-scrollpanescrollpanestyle-registered)